# Cambiar color de input SIN utilizar webkit

Tags: html, css, input

tengo una gran duda.
Me dan un código input, y me piden que cambie el color del texto a pink, y el font-size a 15px. La cosa es que me piden que lo haga SIN UTILIZAR el webkit.

El código que me dan es el siguiente:

```
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" id="email1">
```

Y yo había puesto ::placeholder y me cambiaba el color y demás, pero el ejercicio me da error, supongo que es porque estoy utilizando ::webkit (?)
Este es el código que yo había puesto:

```
    ::placeholder{color:pink;
                  font-size:15px;}
```

¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo hacerlo sin el ::webkit? Porque me estoy volviendo loca...

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: mmm... te refieres por ejemplo a esto?  `<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" id="email1" style="color:pink; font-size:15px;" >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si te refieres a esto:

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" id="email1" style="color:pink; font-size:15px;" >
```

o más bien a esto en un archivo CSS (usando los [selectores de CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)):

```
[name=email] {
    color:pink;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

donde por ejemplo quedaría así:

```css
[name=email] {
    color:pink;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" id="email1">
```

Comment: Sí, era eso, también lo había intentado pero se ve que algo no habría escrito bien y no me lo ha cogido...Gracias!